# submitting the form in iframe and redirect the whole page

Tags: forms, iframe, redirect

I guess I have an easy question, I have not found the right answer yet though.
I have an iframe in my page that comes from an external domain. After submitting the form which is inside this iframe, I would like to redirect the whole page, not just the content inside the iframe - I guess the right way to achieve might be via "target" attribute.

The sample html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>main page</h1>
    <iframe src="http://example.com">
      <form url="http://example.com/action">
        ...
      </form>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Submitting the form should show me the result of submitting the POST request as a new page (not in the iframe)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have put `target='_parent'` in the iframe but I haven't done this initially in the `form` element. After adding `target='_parent'` attribute to `form` it started to work as expected.

Comment: thanks Sir! I was going crazy with this...
so do you need to change the iframe too or only the form?

Comment: @d.raev I have changed both if I remember correctly and it worked. I think it didn't work when I changed only one, but feel free to check it yourself :)

Comment: Only the `target` attribute on the `<form>` element is significant here. There is no `target` attribute for `<iframe>` elements and adding it will make your HTML invalid.

Comment: In one particular scenario, I was required to use `target="_top"`, otherwise the form would post to its action in a new tab. Switching from `_parent` to `_top` allowed the form to post into the current window, completely taking it over as desired.

Comment: Thanks man! I was facing issue in Asp.net with MSAL integration. Azure was blocking redirect from iFrame. I just put this tag in <form> under <iframe> and it is working perfectly for me. :-)

Comment: _blank works as well if you'd like to open a new tab. Although the first time, it was blocked, and I had to tell the browser to allow pop-ups from the such and such.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `target` attribute to the `form` within the `iframe`:

```
<form action="foobar" method="post" target="_parent">
  ...
</form>
```