# How to force redirect in an iframe to open in parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I have an iframe opening page Y inside page X. And Page Y contains a form, on submit of which it redirects to page Z. But Page Z is opening inside the iframe but I want it to open in the parent window, basically on submit of the form it should redirect to page Z from page X in the parent window.
Any solution for this ?

Comment: show your code what you have done for it?

Comment: `window.top.location.href = 'http://www.redirectme.com'`.

Comment: Its not a link its a form on submit of which is redirecting to a different page but as the form is inside iframe, so the new page is also opening inside the iframe. I want it to open in the parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to use [target="_parent" element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) for the form inside iframe. Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352547/4073877). In such case you do not need to use JavaScript.