# IFrame should redirect top-level window and not inside of the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, iframe

Currently I want that an IFrame redirects the *top-level* windows on form submission. I've got this to work with a large javascript which is attached to the `load` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sampleIFrame').load(function (e) {
        $("iframe").each(function () {
            try {
                $(this).contents().find('form').each(function (index) {
                    try {
                        var action = $(this).attr('action');
                        console.log('Yep, action:: ' + action);

                        // Check whether the process was successfull
                        if (action.indexOf('success/1') > -1) {
                            window.location.href = action;
                        }// Check whether the process was successfull
                        if (action.indexOf('error/1') > -1) {
                            window.location.href = action;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        // Can be ignored here
                    }
                });

            } catch (e) {
                // Can be ignored here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a more easy way to do this? I've played around with the `sandbox` attribute but this does not help.

The problem here is, that the user sees the page first `unload`, than `loading` and after that, the top-level window will be redirected. But I want the window to redirect immediately and not in the `iframe` itself.

**EDIT**

This seems not to work, cause I've no access to the `form` element inside the `iframe`.

Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [submitting the form in iframe and redirect the whole page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352195/submitting-the-form-in-iframe-and-redirect-the-whole-page)

Comment: @PatrickEvans what is if i have no access to the `form` element of the site inside the iframe?

Comment: No access as in no file write permission or the site in the iframe is an external domain? If its the former simply access the form the way you are already doing and just do `$(this).prop("target","_parent")`. If its the latter there is nothing you can do as you have no access at all

Comment: It's a different domain. The side enables some input fields and after submitting, it should redirect to another side on my page.

Comment: If its a different domain then `$(this).contents()` should not work at all as you have no access to the iframe contents when its an external domain

Comment: Ok, than I have to use my "solution".