# Submitting the form in iframe and redirect the whole page without touching iframe page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set credit card typing area (in a payment gatway) as iframe. example.com is just a form. When form is submitted I wan to load it as whole page instead of inside iframe.

```
  <iframe src="http://example.com">    </iframe>
```

[submitting the form in iframe and redirect the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352195/submitting-the-form-in-iframe-and-redirect-the-whole-page) is a very similar question.

But unfortunately I can't access to the form since that is bank page.

So how to load the whole page when form submit without touching iframe page?

Comment: Funny profile, man.

Comment: @Littlee ha ha.. Seems like you have read the profile description too. But it isn't funny. It is true :-)

Comment: What payment gateway are you integrating? I've integrated with Alipay before, it's also a iframe, and it will call a global function after submitting the form, so I can config what to do after submitting

Comment: @Littlee This is a local one